# no suitable user-defined conversion from "lambda []()-><error-type>" to "const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>"

Tags: c++

I try to implement lambda function:-

```
    vector<int> numbers;
    int value = 0;

    cout << "Pushing back...\n";
    while (value >= 0) {
        cout << "Enter number: ";
        cin >> value;
        if (value >= 0)
            numbers.push_back(value);
    }
    print( [numbers]() ->  
    {

        cout << "Vector content: {  ";
        for (const int& num : numbers)
            cout << num << "  ";
        cout << "}\n\n";  


    });
```

I got an error:-

```
1.Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Source  Suppression State
Error (active)  E0312   no suitable user-defined conversion from "lambda []()-><error-type>" to "const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>" exists    consoleapplication  C:\Users\insmitr\source\repos\consoleapplication\consoleapplication.cpp 46  IntelliSense    

2.Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Source  Suppression State
Error (active)  E0079   expected a type specifier   consoleapplication  C:\Users\insmitr\source\repos\consoleapplication\consoleapplication.cpp 47  IntelliSense
```

Could you please help me in this regards

Comment: You're passing a lambda to the print function when the print function accepts a vector? Also, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You must insert a type to use as the return type after the `->`. If I insert `void` the code can absolutely work given the appropriate definition of `print`, e.g. `template<class T> void print(T&& t) {std::forward<T>(t)();}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `print` accepts a `vector<int>` but while calling `print` you're passing a lambda and since there is no implicit conversion from the lambda to the vector, you get the mentioned error.

You don't necessarily need to call `print` as you can just call the lambda itself as shown below. Other way is to make `print` a function template so that it can accept any callable and then call the passed callable.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    int value = 0;

    cout << "Pushing back...\n";
    while (value >= 0) {
        cout << "Enter number: ";
        cin >> value;
        if (value >= 0)
            numbers.push_back(value);
    }
//-------------------vvvv------>void added here
    ( [numbers]() -> void 
    {

        cout << "Vector content: {  ";
        for (const int& num : numbers)
            cout << num << "  ";
        cout << "}\n\n";  

//----vv---->note the brackets for calling
    })();
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/x00TsqnRJ)